# UISwipeGestureRecognizer from specific location

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

so I have a button and TouchUpInside event already assigned to that button.
When the button is pressed, it animates a menu from bottom of the screen to about half of the screen.

But I want the user to be able to swipe UP from WITHIN the button to animate the menu and swipe DOWN from WITHIN the button to animate away.

I was able to figure out up and down swipe gestures but they work on the whole view.
so when user swipes up anywhere on the view, it animates.

How can I get the LocationOfTouch and limit the swipe's starting point from within the button?

This is what I have right now:

I delclared:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer UpSwipe;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer DownSwipe;
```

And then this is how I used them:

```
    public void setupGestures() {

        this.UpSwipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer () {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up,
            Enabled = true
        };

        this.DownSwipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer () {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down,
            Enabled = true
        };

        UpSwipe.AddTarget (animateRecentActivityView);
        DownSwipe.AddTarget (animateAwayRecentActivityView);

        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (UpSwipe);
        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (DownSwipe);
    }
```

Comment: You're adding the gesture recognizer to the view, what if you add it to the button?

Comment: I tried that but the entire swipe has to be inside the button for that to work and of course, the button is too small for that. It doesn't recognize it as a swipe.

Comment: Actually my button was inside a view of it's own and that's why it wasn't working. I put the button outside the view and applied the swipeGesture to the button, and it worked out.  Thanks

Comment: You can instead use only one gesture recognizer and check for its state `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and keep animating your view along with the changes in location obtained from method `locationInView:` every time it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to figure it out.
My button was inside a view and even though I added a swipe gesture to the button, somehow it didn't work.  Once I removed it from the view, adding swipeGesture to the button directly worked perfectly.

```
        this.UpSwipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer () {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up,
            Enabled = true
        };

        this.DownSwipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer () {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down,
            Enabled = true
        };

        UpSwipe.AddTarget (animateRecentActivityView);
        DownSwipe.AddTarget (animateAwayRecentActivityView);

        btnAct_HomeRecentActivity.AddGestureRecognizer (UpSwipe);
        btnAct_HomeRecentActivity.AddGestureRecognizer (DownSwipe);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the LocationOfTouch and limit the swipe's starting point from within the button?

In pure Cocoa touch you can override `UIView`'s method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

parameter "touches" contains a set of `UITouch`

call `UITouch`'s method

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

you get the location of touch point

Comment: That can work to get the PointF location of the touch but how can I use that to make it work with swipeGesture? I want user's touch to be inside the button and when they swipe up, a menu animates.  But the swipe's end location will not be in the button because button is too small for the whole swipe